# How to apply restraints on member which is on grade (continuous support)?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

[image]

ETABS has option for providing restraints on joints, but how does one provide restraint to an entire member which is supported by ground ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a slab-on-grade problem, open the program and from the main page, select "Define" tap, and find " Define Spring Constants" in the sub-manual to select the type of spring and provide the required data.

I suggest reading the ETABS User Manual first to learn how to model a slab-on-grade structure.

Comment: Thanks for answering, is it same in case of frame members (beams) ?
If so, how do I calculate spring constants ?

Comment: For foundation, your geotechnical engineer should provide the "soil modulus:, or you can use the allowable soil pressure to approximate. Soil property is universal for any structural system that deals with soil-structure interaction.